# API welcomescreen.close(); doesnt works javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to close `welcomescreen` using `welcomescreen.open(false);`. I'm also trying `welcomescreen.close();` but it doesn't work either.

Can somebody show me right way to solve this?
I can hide welcome screen by set  `open: false`

but when i put in event like this in app.js it still opened

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
  this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  StatusBar.styleLightContent();
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  }, 0 - 0);
  welcomescreen.open(false);
},
```

Here welcomescreen.js based on this [library](https://github.com/valnub/welcomescreen.js)

Comment: Don't add library code here, just put your code, and did you create instance of `Welcomescreen`? Are you getting any error?

Comment: i didnt get error when i write welcomescreen.open(false);

Comment: but i dont know its right way to use this "welcomescreen.open(false);"

Comment: In the doc this is mentioned. The following methods are available on a welcomescreen instance

`welcomescreen.open();`         // Open the screen
`welcomescreen.close(); `      // Closes it

Comment: Where are you creating the instance of welcomescreen ?

Comment: in app.js
im trying welcomescreen.close(); its still opened sir

Comment: i cant close the welcomescree by do  welcomescreen.close(); in event listener, but change open : true to open : false do. how i change open : true to open : false programmatically ... sir?

Comment: Log `welcomescreen` inside onDeviceReady function, are you getting Welcomescreen object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcomescreen.open(false);
is not work try read documentation first.

try this

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
  this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
  StatusBar.styleLightContent();
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
  }, 0 - 0);
  welcomescreen.close(true);
},
```